# Display scene at lower resolution in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am looking for a way to display a three.js viewport at half resolution (or double size depending on how you look at it).

Three.js [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) states that

> [Y]ou can also give setSize smaller values, like window.innerWidth/2 and window.innerHeight/2, for half the resolution. This does not mean that the game will only fill half the window, but rather look a bit blurry and scaled up.

The actual result, however, is that the viewport is sclaed to half size.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4p3bcua/) shows the non-expected behaviour.

Looking at the [API](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer) there is a `setSize` and a `setViewport` method, but neither allows me to have a scaled up viewport.

There is a [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325156/three-js-changing-resolution) here on SO that gives one way of doing it with CSS, but I am looking for a non-CSS related way if possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

2pha's answer is correct and has been implemented in threejs with the `setPixelRatio()` method, so you can write even fewer lines. The main interest with this method is that is is consistent with the window property `window.devicePixelRatio` as recalled in a comment.

This is an important feature to add to your boilerplate if you care about mobile / tablet devices. In your HTML header you should have this meta tag : `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'/>`.

- If you do not have this tag your `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` values will be bigger than your device needs, creating a bigger framebuffer and that can reduce your framerate.
- But at this opposite if you do have this tag, without setting the pixel ratio, your framebuffer will then be too small... [CSS pixel vs screen pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382331/how-a-css-pixel-size-is-calculated) [story](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html).

That is why you add this line in javascript

```
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
```

It needs the `setSize` to be called after :

```
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize( innerWidth, innerHeight );
```

Comment: Ahh, I thought there must be an easier way

Comment: Based on the ThreeJS examples I would amend this to renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio * 0.5) etc

Comment: 1/2 the devicePixelRatio seems to give you 1/4 of the total pixels

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there is a better way but you could scale the dom element right after it has been added.

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
renderer.domElement.style.width = renderer.domElement.width * 2 + 'px';
renderer.domElement.style.height = renderer.domElement.height * 2 + 'px';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x4p3bcua/4/

Though this is still doing it via css in a round about way.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Even though your answer is technically correct, I choose to accept Atrahasis answer, since it uses the official API.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have css style for canvas:

```
<style>
    canvas { width:100%; height:100%;}
</style>
```

And set the third argument to false:

```
renderer.setSize( renWidth, renHeight, false);
```

This will disable the hardcoded styling of the canvas inside the function, so the canvas will use your custom 100% width and height style.